# Google Sheet Filtering Issue with Webhook Data: Seeking Solution

Tags: google-sheets, filtering, webhooks

I'm currently facing an issue with my Google Sheet. I have a sheet that receives data from a WordPress Elementor webhook. When using the "webhook for sheet" approach, everything works well. However, I need to filter the data and populate it into five separate sheets using the following formula:

`=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY({General!AG:AG, General!AF:AF, General!F:F, General!G:G, General!N:N, General!L:L, General!O:O, General!Q:Q}, "SELECT * WHERE Col4 = 'BCN Gràcia'", 1), COUNTA({General!AG:AG, General!AF:AF, General!F:F, General!G:G, General!N:N, General!L:L, General!O:O, General!Q:Q})-1, 8)`

Unfortunately, this formula gives me an error. However, when I use the following formula to retrieve all data from another sheet in a different Gmail account, it works fine and I'm able to separate the data:

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1OUqdeCH14DywJm--uS8u9BUudcZf0NhVTbpu_PKlwkM", "General!A:BD"), "SELECT * WHERE Col1 = 'BCN Gràcia'")`

It's puzzling that the same function doesn't work in the account that receives data directly through the webhook. I'm hoping someone can provide a solution or shed some light on this issue.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Best regards,

Comment: I ran your formula and it works w/out error. Using your formula(`=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY({`), would you please edit your question to supply some dummy data, based on that data include a snapshot of the error message, and also based on that data include an example of the result that you expect from this formula.